How can I fix the white "bleed" along the edges of a scanned image?
I have a scanned image (not done by me so redoing the scan is not an option).
At all the edges of the image have a white bleed from the edge onto the image that I would like to get rid of without losing the original image.
Here is an example (this is just a part of the image and in this example only the top edge is bleeding):

(open the image to see it fully as it's not visible here in the inline preview)

This problem is likely caused by some kind of light leaking at the edge of the scanner, or possibly because the copy was not lying completely flat. Even a fault with the scanner can't be ruled out.
Apart from rescanning, a practical attempt at a fix is possible, but it won't be perfect, because getting the exact adjustment to counteract the fault in the scan is not easy and it will require some trial and error.

Add a curves adjustment layer, and pull the curve downwards a touch.



At the top edge of the image, apply a Foreground (white) to Background (black) gradient on the layer mask, to apply the curves adjustment just to that area

Pull the mid point of the gradient towards the white end (highlighted red below)


Click to see larger
Here's an animated detail of the before and after

As you can see, this is still not a perfect fix as there is a stubborn line of lighter pixels along the top, and so a slight crop may be required to remove them entirely.

In theory you could darken the leaks afterwards by inserting in Photoshop a Levels or Curves adjustment layer which pulls the black level back to zero. But making the right gradient layer mask to the adjustment layer can be difficult. It's easy just in your current example which has a simple looking leak only in one edge. If the leaks are as simple at the remaining 3 edges you can insert 3 more adjustment layers; every adjustment layer compensate only the leak of one edge.
In the future it's better to try to stop the light leakage. Place a black paper between the image and the cover of the scanner bed to prevent any white background to generate multiple reflections inside the scanner glass. Cover the scanner with a non-transparent blanket to stop the room light entering to the scan between the scanner cover and the glass. Remove the blanket soon to prevent overheating.

It may be that the image is taking too much of the scanner glass and too close to the edge of the glass.
You may do better to scan the image a couple times, placing it in the center of the glass. Then stitch the pieces back together in Photoshop. Or scan twice, rotating it 180° for the second scan so you can overlay the two images covering the diffused "glow" on the one end.
